# FreeBSD: Is the default user shell `tcsh`?

Tags: shell, freebsd, tcsh, csh

I was recently reading a tutorial for `tcsh` and it said that the default user shell for FreeBSD was `tcsh` and I was surprised.

**For FreeBSD, is the default user shell `tcsh`?**

Comment: You might want to read [this section](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/shells.html) of the handbook. But there are only two shells in the base system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The FreeBSD documentation I found](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/linux-users/shells.html) says:

> FreeBSD uses
>   [`tcsh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tcsh&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports)
>   as the default root shell and the Bourne shell-compatible
>   [`sh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports)
>   as the default user shell.

Comment: It's actually the Almquist shell.

Comment: The documentation link is correct. Of course it is!